# Access to undefined property

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

Can someone help me to find out why I'm getting the error message "Access to undefined property: invalid & count on the following snipped?

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;    
invalid.visible = false;    
txtNumber.restrict = "0-9";    
var sum:Number = 0

btnCount.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, count);

btnReset.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);
{

     function add (evt:MouseEvent)
     {
         sum=sum+Number (txtNumber.text);
         txtSum.text=String(sum)
     }
     function reset (MouseEvent)
     {
         sum=0;   
         txtNumber.text = "0"    
         txtSum.text = "0"
     }

     if (txtSum.text=="NaN"){
         invalid.visible=true;
     }
}
```

Comment: hard to tell since this isnt a complete code sample, varables invalid and count do not look to be defined here...or that's the problem, they aren't deifned.

Comment: Because your code refers to `invalid` and `count` but such things do not exist based on the code you posted.

Comment: Most likely,  `invalid` and/or `count` do not exist (or don't have their instance name(s) set) on the keyframe where this code you've posted is.    You may have them on some other frame, but they need to be present and named properly on the frame where the code runs.